# From one host, cannot hit an HTTP url with SoapClient

Tags: php, soap-client

I have one problem in ONE host: I cannot access an HTTP url (say, http://foo-bar.com:9999/Path/To/My/Soap.svc?wsdl).

Hitting such URL from my localhost (running PHP 5.4) works fine. However, hitting such url from my target server (running PHP 5.5) brings me this SoapFault:

> Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://foo-bar.com:9999/Path/To/My/Soap.svc?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://foo-bar.com:9999/Path/To/My/Soap.svc?wsdl"

(I did not disclose the URL due to contract policies)

What can I check? (Since the url is not in HTTPS but just HTTP, openssl should be discarded)

Code:

```
new SoapClient(
    'http://foo-bar.com:9999/Path/To/My/Soap.svc?wsdl',
    array('uri' => 'http://foo-bar.com/wsdl/schema/')
);
```

Comment: Can you ping it from the server? Does the target site block your site? Does your firewall block outgoing requests to that site?

Comment: Yep. Is not a protocol issue -I thought there was something to do with PHP version / SoapClient version / Soap protocol. The connection is being refused

Comment: "The connection is being refused" - Contact the people who can grant you access at the other end. Something is blocking your server at their end.

Comment: Yep. However the problem is not at the end, but in the hosting service. If I have another question I'll ask it in serverfault.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Found it: There's nothing wrong in the SOAP client between PHP versions. They remain compatible between -at least- 5.2 and 5.5. So there's nothing weird to test here, but just simple connection tests.

Issues like this should be tested with: `file_get_contents('http://foo-bar.com:9999/Path/To/My/Soap.svc?wsdl')` (modern PHP versions have fopen_wrappers active by default).

The answer? Connections are refused. That's why I get such error.